# .NET 6: how to get user-secrets working in a class library?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

I am trying to seperate my Data Acccess from my WebAPI.

So I made a simple .NET 6 class library `(dotnet new classlib -f net6.0 )` for my `entity framework core 6` models and context.

I ran `dotnet user-secrets init` in the WebAPI project and then copied the `<UserSecretsId>` from the `.csproj` file to the `.csproj` file of the DAL project.

```cs
    // (school.WebAPI.csproj) added reference in School.WebAPI to School.DAL
    <ProjectReference Include="..\School.DAL\School.DAL.csproj" />
```

Now I am trying to scaffold the database.

> dotnet ef dbcontext scaffold name=ConnectionStrings:SchoolDev Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer -o Models --context-dir Data --schema dbo -f

Which generates the following error:

> System.InvalidOperationException: A named connection string was used, but the name 'ConnectionStrings:SchoolDev' was not found in the application's configuration.

When I run the same command in the `WebAPI` project it works perfectly.

I read something about `var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);` being used by the CLI to read the `secrets.json`. But I got confused because I don't feel like `WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args)` belongs in a `DAL` project.

How do you set up access to user-secrets from cli in a class library?

Comment: You probably shouldn’t. Instead expose an interface for the end application to pass config/secrets in.

Comment: @Dai  I didn't understand. Could you give me an example or link to a resource to learn about it?

Comment: Did you try running the command from the solution root with `-s path/to/API_project -p path/to/SQL_project`? This way it uses the startup project (-s) to figure out configuration and the project (-p) to locate EF context.

Comment: @juunas that might be the answer, going to try it

Comment: @juunas it worked, thanks! I have been struggling for a whole day while the solution is so simple.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can run the EF command in the solution root with `-s path/to/API_project -p path/to/SQL_project`.
This way it uses the startup project (-s) to figure out configuration and the project (-p) to locate EF context.

Documentation: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/cli/dotnet#target-project-and-startup-project